# How do I set up a C# Shared Logic for either Xamarin Apps or Blazor Apps?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, model-view-controller, blazor

I'm very new so sorry if I sound noob.
So I'm aware that Xamarin Forms is mainly a Front-end UI that uses a shared C# logic. However, I want to know this:

1. As a student trying to wrap his head around ASP.NET MVC and Xamarin, **Is it possible that Xamarin Forms, and Web application share the same C# shared logic?**
2. If it is possible, **do I first create a .NET solution to build up all the shared logics**, then depending on which platform I would like to have the views on, **I could either use Xamarin or Blazor App to reference the previous .NET solution to use that shared logic for the views needed for them?**

Sorry - I do require a little guidance on this. Thank you.

Comment: How about putting the shared logic in a Class Library, and have both the ASP.NET and Xamarin apps reference that Class Library?

Comment: Check out this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio  The guide is using the library in a Console app, but the same idea applies for any app kind. Avoid putting any UI logic into the library if you plan to share it between Xamarin and Blazor.